# Macbook Pro using all the bandwidth

Tags: network, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

My Macbook Pro is using all my bandwidth and making my entire network unstable.

I thought this could be the iCloud Photo Library, so I paused for a day, didn't change anything, turned off iPhoto process, no change. I disabled iCloud Drive, same issue.

Regarding Activity Monitor, this is most likely because of nsurlsessiond,
Regarding my router :

```
2015-12-21  10:39:48    Kevins-MBP  s3-3-w.amazonaws.com 
2015-12-21  10:39:37    Kevins-MBP  gblon-edge.icloud-content.com.akadns.net
2015-12-21  10:39:31    Kevins-MBP  s3-3-w.amazonaws.com
2015-12-21  10:39:24    Kevins-MBP  gblon-edge.icloud-content.com.akadns.net
2015-12-21  10:39:21    Kevins-MBP  gblon-edge.icloud-content.com.akadns.net 
2015-12-21  10:39:19    Kevins-MBP  gblon-edge.icloud-content.com.akadns.net 
2015-12-21  10:38:41    Kevins-MBP  p04-ckdatabase-current.edge.icloud.apple-dns.net 
2015-12-21  10:38:26    Kevins-MBP  p04-keyvalueservice-current.edge.icloud.apple-dns.net 
2015-12-21  10:38:24    Kevins-MBP  p04-keyvalueservice-current.edge.icloud.apple-dns.net 
2015-12-21  10:38:23    Kevins-MBP  p04-contacts.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:38:21    Kevins-MBP  p04-keyvalueservice-current.edge.icloud.apple-dns.net 
2015-12-21  10:38:11    Kevins-MBP  keyvalueservice.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:38:10    Kevins-MBP  p04-sharedstreams.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:38:09    Kevins-MBP  stats-public.grammarly.io 
2015-12-21  10:38:04    Kevins-MBP  p04-escrowproxy.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:38:00    Kevins-MBP  p04-escrowproxy.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:37:59    Kevins-MBP  p04-streams.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:37:59    Kevins-MBP  lcdn-locator.apple.com 
2015-12-21  10:37:58    Kevins-MBP  p04-escrowproxy.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:37:56    Kevins-MBP  p04-mailws.icloud.com 
2015-12-21  10:37:56    Kevins-MBP  p04-quota-current.edge.icloud.apple-dns.net
```

I know amazon is probably because of Photo.app / iCloud Photo Library. So is my only option is to turn that off? or could I be wrong?

[image: Network Acitvity]

Comment: Did you tried to kill nsurlsessiond after the pause for a day ? Terminal -> killall nsurlsessiond

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually I just reboot the computer and this seems to be gone, for some reason even if you pause iCloud library from the photo.app setting you need to reboot osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nsurlsessiond` is used by other software to make requests on their behalf, the most common source of large amounts of data being transfered with it on workstations and end-user devices is iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Drive.

You can watch for filesystem activity in `~/Library/Caches/CloudKit` if photo sync doesn't seem to be the source. It is possible to have a condition where sync operations with iCloud Drive don't reconcile as expected and your workstation will be re-fetching data — you will see evidence of this in logs for `bird(8)` for the user.